# Magento2.2 PHP Fatar Error in config:show

Tags: php, magento2.2, fatal-error

I casually run `php bin/magento config:show` and it showed me the following PHP Fatal Error, but I don't have a clue, because the site works ok.

```
........
analytics/subscription/enabled - 1
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group::hasBackendModel() in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShow/ValueProcessor.php:100
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(197): Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigShow\ValueProcessor->process('default', '', 'Magento Analyti...', 'analytics/integ...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(202): Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigShowCommand->outputResult(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), 'Magento Analyti...', 'analytics/integ...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(202): Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigShowCommand->outputResult(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Array, 'analytics')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(161): Magento\Config\C in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShow/ValueProcessor.php on line 100

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group::hasBackendModel() in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShow/ValueProcessor.php:100
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(197): Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigShow\ValueProcessor->process('default', '', 'Magento Analyti...', 'analytics/integ...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(202): Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigShowCommand->outputResult(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), 'Magento Analyti...', 'analytics/integ...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(202): Magento\Config\Console\Command\ConfigShowCommand->outputResult(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Array, 'analytics')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShowCommand.php(161): Magento\Config\C in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Console/Command/ConfigShow/ValueProcessor.php on line 100
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. (Magento 2.2.4)

Comment: Same error same line, on 2.3.0.  Did you find cause?